How can I include data from a dataframe when plotting a lmer-model (in R)?
1 Time instead of Time4
I calculated a Multilevel Model and included (among other IVs), time4 as time^4. Now, I would like to plot the effect of time on my DV. However, I would like to include the variable "time" which was not included in the model. Basically, I only need to change the axis labels...
The resulting graph should look like this one:
plot_model(rq1_model2, type = "pred", show.values = TRUE)


I only want to include the fixed effects and keep the model simple.
How do I do that?
2 Adding a second graph to the plot
Additionally, I would like to include a second similar model in the same window / plot for comparison. This second graph should only be depicted for values of time from 0 onwards (there are negative values for time for the first value).
Actually, the model only contains values for the time4-values referring to values of time from 0 onwards.
Thank you for any ideas in advance!
3 What I already tried
plot_model(rq1_model2, type = "pred", show.values = TRUE)

But I don't know how to include data from a data frame additional to the model.
I also tried including the variable time with "^4" instead of time4 (where I calculated the variable before). However, the result is not right.
My model:
rq1_model2 <- lmerTest::lmer(proc_learn ~ ... + time4 + (1| code),
                             data = data, REML = FALSE)

Another option would be to only include data from a data frame. But then I would still need to get the regression results and insert the variable time. I could see exporting the regression results into a data frame and adding the variable time. However, I don't know how to get to the regression graph.
A Minimal Reproducible Example (Thanks to @Ben Bolker)
library(lmerTest)
ss <- transform(sleepstudy, Days4 = Days^4)
m <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days4 + (1|Subject), ss) 


Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could we have a [mcve] please? Would library(lmerTest); ss <- transform(sleepstudy, Days4 = Days^4); m <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days4 + (1|Subject), ss) work?

Yes! Thank you very much for the example as well as the corrections in my request!

I'm afraid this is rather complicated, but it might do what you want.
set up example, fit two models
library(lmerTest)
ss <- within(sleepstudy,
{
    Dayminus <- Days - 4
    Days4 <- Dayminus^4
})
m1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days4 + (1|Subject), ss)
m2 <- update(m1, subset = (Dayminus > 0))

set up new data frame for predictions
You can predict based on the original data, but this is better if your original data are sparse/out of order/etc.. You will also have to set any non-focal values in your model to their mean values (or whatever reference value you want to use).
library(ggplot2)
pframe <- with(ss,
               data.frame(Dayminus = seq(min(Dayminus), max(Dayminus),
                                         length.out = 101)))
pframe <- transform(pframe, Days4 = Dayminus^4)

make predictions; get SEs and construct CIs
Set up a utility function because we have to do the same thing twice.
mkpred <- function(m) {
    pp <- predict(m, newdata = pframe, se.fit = TRUE, re.form = NA)
    pframe <- with(pp,
                   cbind(pframe, ## uses external pframe
                         data.frame(pred = fit,
                                    lwr = fit - 1.96*se.fit,
                                    upr = fit + 1.96*se.fit)))
    return(pframe)
}
pred1frame <- mkpred(m1)
pred2frame <- mkpred(m2)
## restrict predictions for the second model to positive values of 'Dayminus'
pred2frame <- pred2frame[pred2frame$Dayminus>0,]

create the plot
Draw a line and a semi-transparent ribbon for each model. (If you have several models, or if you want to have an automatic legend, you need to row-bind the two data frames along with a factor variable which says model 1, model 2 ...)
ggplot(pred1frame, aes(Dayminus, pred)) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_line(data=pred2frame, col = "red") +
    geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=lwr, ymax = upr), alpha = 0.2, color=NA, fill = "black") +
    geom_ribbon(data =pred2frame,
                aes(ymin=lwr, ymax = upr), alpha = 0.2, color=NA, fill = "red") 



Thank you very much for your work and explanations! I will check it out and reply here to say whether it worked.
